# Puzzled by when copy of vars to func params happens when using GCD

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch

I’m just learning Swift and was looking at Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) for some CPU intensive tasks. Here are (I believe) all the relevant bits of code I’m puzzled by:

```
// global declarations
var digits        = [Int]()    // where the square's digits reside
var perm_q        = [[Int]]()  // where we accumulate permutations to check later
Let perm_q_max    = 1000       // how many permutations we queue before checking them
var enq_count     = 0          // how many times we've called check_squares
var N             = 3          // size of N x N square
let work_q = DispatchQueue.global()  // returns a global, concurrent dispatch queue
let work_g = DispatchGroup()         // returns a group we put all our work into

// func which is enqueued onto a GCD queue
func check_squares( cnt: Int, perm_ary: [[Int]]) { ... }

// func which calls enqueues check_squares() onto global GCD queue
func permute( k: Int, ary: inout [Int]) {

  if k == 1 {
    
    perm_q.append( ary)  // queue up this permutation for later magic checking

    // if we've queued up enough permutations, then dispatch check_squares()
    if ( perm_q.count >= perm_q_max) {
        enq_count += 1
        // --> let p: [[Int]] = perm_q  // make a local copy
        work_q.async( group: work_g) {      // assign work all to one group
        check_squares( cnt: enq_count,    // check to see if any square is magic
                       perm_ary: p)
      }
      perm_q = [[Int]]()                  // clear out previous permutations
    }
  }

  else { ... }
}

// main
    
digits = Array( 1 ... ( N * N))  // fill digits with digits 1...N^2
permute( k: digits.count, ary: &digits)  // creates permutations and checks for magic squares
```

The problem I’m having is that unless I uncomment the line just above work_q.async() in permute(), when check_squares() starts, ary has zero elements when I expect it to have 1,000 elements. Right after I enqueue check_squres() to GCD on the global async queue, I do perm_q = [Int] which empties array perm_q to be ready to collect the next 1,000 elements.

I’m guessing there is a race condition between starting check_squares() and emptying perm_q, and the emptying occurs before check_squares() starts, but I’m puzzled as to why this race occurs. I understood that the call to check_squares() would make a copy of perm_q.

One explanation I thought of is that the copy of perm_q into check_squares()’s param ary doesn’t happen until GCD starts to execute check_squares(). By the time this happens, perm_q has been emptied. Is that when the copy of perm_q into ary happens and not when check_squares is enqueued? Making the local copy of global var perm_q into var p local to permute() and passing p to check_squares() during the enqueue makes local var p stick around since the reference from check_squares() in the queue keeps array p from disappearing even after permute() exits. Does this sound right?

Other than making the local copy of perm_q into p, is there a preferred method of handing this?

Thanks, Eric

Comment: Unrelated to the question at hand, but how many of these concurrent calls may be taking place at any given time? The number of worker threads is quite limited and this code suspiciously looks like it could easily result in thread explosion, exhausting those worker threads (at which point you can have all sorts of unintended behaviors). We generally reach for `concurrentPerform` for optimal utilization of threads, though there are other solutions, too. But avoid unbridled concurrency.

Comment: And I don’t see how you’re saving the results, but make sure to synchronize that action (with locks or its own synchronization queue). You might want to run this through [TSAN](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_memory_thread_and_crash_issues_early) if you haven’t already.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of thread explosion, and I haven't seen it yet, but I haven't really done anything to control for it. This little problem is just a learning aid and will be abandoned shortly, so I'm not too worried about it, but thanks for the pointers you've included. I will learn about them.

Comment: One additional question about thread explosion: Is it common practice to check to see how many threads are available and only issue new threads if the thread pool has some free threads as a means to avoid thread explosion? I haven't see any properties or calls to return the number of a) threads that I've created that are still running or b) the number of available threads remaining.

Comment: GCD doesn’t offer API to check the threads available or in use, cores available, etc., AFAIK. I suspect that one theoretically could drop into lower level APIs, but that’s practically unheard of. Generally we just use `concurrentPerform` which automatically is optimized for the number of cores available (which is great for compute-intensive parallel algorithms). Or sometimes we use the operation queue `maxConcurrentOperationCount` or the non-zero semaphore pattern to use some reasonable/arbitrary number to avoid thread explosion. We just steer well clear of the 64 worker thread limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Other than making the local copy ..., is there a preferred method of handing this?

The simplest way to give that other thread its own local copy is through a capture list:

```
queue.async(group: group).async { [array] in
    checkSquares(array)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am unfamiliar with this construct. I'll check it out.

Comment: Can you comment on whether my suspicion about when the var is copied to the GCD function is correct or not? Is it when the func is enqueued or when GCD starts the thread? It is acting like the latter as I see it.

Comment: Yes, you have to use this capture list syntax or manually copying yourself. In the absence of that, you have a race condition where it wouldn’t be copied until the method was called.

Comment: Rob, yes, the [array] value capture syntax does the trick and performs somewhat faster than me making a local copy to pass in. Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. I gave your answer an upvote, but I don't have enough reputation points to make it count.